# Break loop in django suddenly after if condition is true for first time

Tags: django

I am having problem in for loop. I want to break the loop suddenly after the if condition is true for the first time ie. i want to print hello only once for one 'for loop' iteration But i come to know that there is no break statement in django. So please tell me how to implement it. I think it can be done through filter but don't know how. Please tell me the approach to do this using filter or other better approach if any.

```
{% for p in subbranch_list %}
        {% if q.id == p.parentbranch_id  %}
                     <h1>Hello</h1>
            {{ break }}
        {% endif %}             
{% endfor %}
```

Actually what i want to do is in my project.html page-
[image]

In above image there is a sidebar contain some branches of project(IT,CS), which is again categorize into  subbranches (IT1, IT2 TE) and there is a small down errow in IT, which i need to display only if atleast one subbranch of it exists in subbranch table.

> My project.html file is-

```
<div id="wrapper" class="midDiv_project">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
            <div class="row" style="background-color:#AEAEAE;">
              <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:hsl(0, 0%, 97%);min-height:580px;margin-lef:-100px;width:21%;border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
                  <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation" >
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/mutech/aboutus/" class="slidebar_a"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                                      <!-- Sidebar -->

{% if branch_list %}
    {% for q in branch_list %}

            <li>
                <a href="#" class="slidebar_a"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> {{ q.branch_title }}    
                    {# hello #}
{% for p in subbranch_list %}
        {% if q.id == p.parentbranch_id  %}
                     <span class="fa arrow"></span></a> 

            {{ break }}
        {% endif %}             
{% endfor %} 
                    {% for p1 in subbranch_list %}
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        {% if q.id == p1.parentbranch_id  %}
                                <li><a href="#" class="slidebar_a">{{ p1.subbranch_title }}</a></li>
                        {% endif %} 
                    </ul>
                    {% endfor %}                

            </li>
    {% endfor %}  
{% endif %}     
                </ul>
            </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->

              </div>
                <div class="col-md-9" >
                    <div>

                        <div class="container" >
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2>Projects List</h2>

            {% if project_list %}
              {% for q in project_list %}
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border:1px solid blak;height:250px;margin:2%">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{ q.project_title }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="../../../media/{{q.project_image}}" alt="Error" style="height:70%; width:100%" /></a><br>
                    <center><p>{{ q.project_title }}</p></center><br>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <p>No Project Found</p>
          {% endif %}
```

> My model.py file is-

```
class branch(models.Model):
    branch_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)



class subbranch(models.Model):
    parentbranch = models.ForeignKey(branch)
    subbranch_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)



class project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Images/Project")
    project_desc = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    project_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_branch = models.ForeignKey(branch)
    project_subbranch = models.ForeignKey(subbranch)
```

there is a line-

> {% if q.id == p.parentbranch_id  %}

and i need that after the if condition is true for first time the loop must terminate.

Comment: IMO, you' better off doing this in your view or a template tag to keep the template code simple.

Comment: But how to implement it in view.py using filter. My table name is subbranch.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're much more likely to get an answer to your question if you demonstrate what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and where you're stuck. "Can you please code this for me?" isn't a great S.O. question.

Comment: Ok please wait let me explore my question.

Comment: Hey @ Brandon, I have edited the question to my actual problem .

Comment: So really what you need to do is only display the caret if there are subcategories, correct?

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75307/discussion-between-brandon-and-rahul-satal).

Comment: Can it be done in view.py file?

Answer (score 1):

Probably best is to do this in your view like [brandon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598683/brandon) suggested. But if you want to do it in your template [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2093/) is an example of how `break` and `continue` are implemented as template filters.